# Flowtype callback's scope doesn't get the type from the parent scope

Tags: javascript, scope, flowtype

#### The Problem:

1. I have a function that accepts a callback and runs it (skipping annotation):

   ```
   const run = (cb) => cb();
   ```
2. I have a function that **REQUIRES** a number:

   ```
   const addTen = (arg: number) => arg + 10;
   ```
3. I have a function that **OPTIONALLY ACCEPTS** a number parameter but inside calls `run()` and inside the callback it calls the `addTen()` passing its optional parameter:

   ```
   const addInCallback = (value: ?number) => {
       // correctly complaints about addTen not accepting null/undefined
       run(() => addTen(value))
   }
   ```
4. **Works:**

   ```
   const addInCallback = (value: ?number) => {
       run(() => {
           if (value) {
               addTen(value)
           }
       })
   }
   ```
5. **Doesn't Work:**

   ```
   const addInCallback = (value: ?number) => {
       if (value) {
           run(() => addTen(value)) // here, value can't be null/undefined
                                    // yet it still complaints
       }
   }
   ```
6. **Doesn't Work:**

   ```
   const addInCallback = (value: ?number) => {
       if (!value) return;
       run(() => addTen(value)) // here, value can't be null/undefined
                                // yet it still complaints
   }
   ```

#### The Question:

If I don't want to do the check inside the callback, how could i approach this so that the callback can understand that the scope above has made it clear that the `value` can not be `null/undefined`?

Comment: As the dup says, you need to either do it in the callback, or assign it to a new variable in the body after refining it, before using it in the callback.

Comment: I knew this would be a duplicate!
I searched and searched but although my English is not that bad, i couldn't think of a way to phrase my searches correctly in order to find answers. Now that I've seen the duplicate, I did another search and found that this is also answered in an Issue in Github. 

Still, your answered helped me understand my problem so thanks @loganfsmyth !

Comment: It's all good. I changed the title of that issue when I linked the duplicate because it wasn't very easy to find before either :)

Comment: Ok I would never find it with the previous title! So thanks for that too i guess!